# persistence.xml - Error parsing XML: XML InputStream(1) Premature end of file

Tags: xml, hibernate, maven

I am getting this error when i'm trying to create an entity manager in my code.

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("puDS1", myproperties);
```

Any hints on why this could be happening? My persistence.xml seems to be a valid xml.

```
ERROR [main] (PersistenceXmlLoader.java:251) - Error parsing XML: XML InputStream(1) Premature end of file.
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:265)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:125)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:52)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.loadURL(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.deploy(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:222)
        ... 4 more
```

THe persistence xml looks like this. Please note that i use maven resource filtering on this persistence.xml, so during compile time ${jar_file_name_ds1} and ${jar_file_name_ds2} is replaced with valid names. I have validated that the final persistence.xml has the values substituted properly. I don;t know if maven resource filtering is messing things up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="puDS1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jar-file>${jar_file_name_ds1}</jar-file>      
      <properties>         
         <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>   
   <persistence-unit name="puDS2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jar-file>${jar_file_name_ds2}</jar-file>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>   
</persistence>
```

Comment: can you post your persistence.xml?

Comment: just updated question with persistence.xml

Comment: I would suggest that the Maven resource filtering replacement is introducing something invalid that is confusing the XML parser.  Can you post the result of the substitution?  This should be available in your `target` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the code was trying to connect to the internet (i presume to get the xsd to validate persistence.xml). When i connected the machine to the internet it started working. I am trying to get over this problem so that i DON'T need to be connected to the internet however that's a different problem.